# react native - validate forms using API requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, react-native, bcrypt

I wanted to validate the password related to a user for modifying password. For better security, I decided to do that in server-side. I used bcryptjs in server to do this. I send user id and a password to the server. The server finds the document(I used MongoDB as DB) from the user's collection, hash the text in the request and compare the hashed text with the hashed password in the user's document. If they match server responded with true  else server responses with false,

I used postman to check the API. It works fine but when I use the code to react-native the response from the API was undefined. Why is that?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  Keyboard, 
  ToastAndroid,
} from 'react-native';
import {GreenButtonSmall} from './../components/customButtons';
import BackArrow from '../components/backArrow';
import axios from 'axios';
import {Formik} from 'formik';
import * as yup from 'yup';

//form validator
const validationScheme = yup.object({
  newPassword: yup.string().min(1),
  reTypeNewPassword: yup.string().min(1),
  oldPassword: yup.string().min(1),
});

export default class AccountSettingsScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      newPassword: '',
      updated_at: new Date(),
      oldPassword: '',
      reNewPassword: '',
      password: '',
    };
    this.updateValues = this.updateValues.bind(this);
    this.checkHashedPassword= this.checkHashedPassword.bind(this);
  }


    checkHashedPassword(id,password){
    //const chekPassword = {id,password}
    const chekPassword = { id  ,  password  }

    axios
      .post(
        'https://ancient-temple.herokuapp.com/users/check',
         chekPassword
        )
      .then(  (res) => {
        const result =   res.data  
       // console.log(result); 
        return  result;
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    //get profile details usind _id
    axios
      .get(
        ' https://ancient-temple.herokuapp.com/users/get/5ecb578fb2b10b0844de4cff',
      )
      .then((res) => {
        const userData = res.data;

        this.setState({...userData, enabled: true});
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }



  updateValues(values) {
    Keyboard.dismiss();
    this.checkHashedPassword('5edca42b9d784d2ee4981654',values['oldPassword']).then(()=>{

    console.log(this.checkHashedPassword('5edca42b9d784d2ee4981654',values['oldPassword']), 'This');
    })


    if (values.newPassword != values.reNewPassword) {
      ToastAndroid.show('Re enter new password correctly', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
    } else if ( !this.checkHashedPassword('5edca42b9d784d2ee4981654',values['oldPassword'])){
      console.log(values['oldPassword']);
      ToastAndroid.show('Re enter old password correctly', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
    } else if (this.checkHashedPassword('5edca42b9d784d2ee4981654',values['oldPassword'])) {
      axios
        .put(
          ' https://ancient-temple.herokuapp.com/users/update/5ec66db7aa16ff3a80870c9a',
          {password: values.newPassword},
        )
        .then((res) => {
          ToastAndroid.show('Update succesfull !', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    }

    //console.log(JSON.stringify({...values}, null, 2));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
          <BackArrow />

          <View style={{height: 590}}>
            <Text style={styles.titleText}>Account settings</Text>

            <View style={styles.card}>
              <Formik
                initialValues={{
                  newPassword: '',
                  reNewPassword: '',
                  oldPassword: '',
                }}
                enableReinitialize
                validationSchema={validationScheme}
                onSubmit={(values) => {
                  this.updateValues(values);
                }}>
                {(props) => (
                  <View>
                    <Text style={styles.inputTitles}>New password</Text>
                    <TextInput
                      placeholder={'Enter new password here'}
                      onChangeText={props.handleChange('newPassword')}
                      value={props.values.newPassword}
                      style={[
                        styles.inputs,
                        ,
                        props.errors.newPassword
                          ? styles.errorText
                          : styles.inputs,
                      ]}
                    />

                    <Text style={styles.inputTitles}>
                      Re enter new password
                    </Text>
                    <TextInput
                      placeholder={'re-enter new password'}
                      onChangeText={props.handleChange('reNewPassword')}
                      value={props.values.reNewPassword}
                      style={[
                        styles.inputs,
                        props.errors.reNewPassword
                          ? styles.errorText
                          : styles.inputs,
                      ]}
                    />
                    <Text style={styles.inputTitles}>Old password</Text>
                    <TextInput
                      placeholder={'Enter old password here'}
                      onChangeText={props.handleChange('oldPassword')}
                      value={props.values.oldPassword}
                      style={[
                        styles.inputs,
                        props.errors.oldPassword
                          ? styles.errorText
                          : styles.inputs,
                      ]}
                    />
                    <Text style={styles.infoText}>
                      {' '}
                      Minimum password length is 6 characters
                    </Text>
                    <View style={styles.buttoContainer}>
                      <GreenButtonSmall
                        text={'Save changes'}
                        onPress={props.handleSubmit}
                      />
                    </View>
                  </View>
                )}
              </Formik>
            </View>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexGrow: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#E4E4E4',
  },

  buttoContainer: {
    position: 'relative',
    marginTop: 20,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },

  titleText: {
    fontFamily: 'Segoe UI',
    fontSize: 30,
    position: 'relative',
    left: '7%',
    top: 72,
  },

  infoText: {
    fontFamily: 'Segoe UI',
    fontSize: 14,
    position: 'relative',
    left: '7%',
    top: '7%',
    marginTop: 1,
  },

  inputTitles: {
    fontFamily: 'Segoe UI',
    fontSize: 18,
    position: 'relative',
    left: '7%',
    top: '8%',
    marginTop: 12,
  },

  cardContent: {
    paddingHorizontal: '10%',
    marginHorizontal: 10,
  },

  inputs: {
    marginTop: 16,
    top: '2%',
    borderBottomColor: '#DADADA',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    width: '70%',
    marginHorizontal: '15%',
    fontFamily: 'Segoe UI',
    fontSize: 16,
    color: '#404040',
    paddingTop: 5,
    paddingBottom: 1,
  },

  errorText: {
    color: 'red',
  },

  card: {
    borderRadius: 6,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    shadowOpacity: 0.3,
    shadowOffset: {width: 1, height: 1},
    marginHorizontal: 4,
    left: '6.5%',
    top: 120,
    height: 390,
    width: '85%',
    margin: 'auto',
    position: 'relative',
  },
});
```